# SWT Button SelectionListener called twice

Tags: java, swt

I use the same widgets on to display different "views" in the same window.
To navigate between the views I use the same "next" button, I only change the listeners that load the next view. And the first time when I click the button it activates two concecutive listeners.

I will try to explain in more detail. The method that loads the first view removes "next" button's listener if there is one (normally there isn't). Then it creates the listener that would load the second view and adds it to the next button. The second view removes the listener and creates and adds a new one that would load the third view when the button is clicked.

So when I load the window and I click "next" button on the first view I have the third view loaded. The worst part is that when I click "back" button the load views in the reverse order and I start again from view one, it works perfectly without skipping the second view.

Here's the code:

```
private Button btnNext;

private SelectionListener nextListener;

private void loadFirstView(){
    if (nextListener != null) {
        btnNext.removeSelectionListener(nextListener);
    }

    nextListener = new SelectionListener() {

        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent event) {

            loadSecondView();

        }

        @Override
        public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent event) {

        }
    };
    btnNext.addSelectionListener(nextListener);
 }


private void loadSecondView(){
    if (nextListener != null) {
        btnNext.removeSelectionListener(nextListener);
    }

    nextListener = new SelectionListener() {

            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent event) {
                loadThirdView();
            }

            @Override
            public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent event) {

            }
        };
    btnNext.addSelectionListener(nextListener);
}

private void loadThirdView(){
    if (nextListener != null) {
        btnNext.removeSelectionListener(nextListener);
    }

    System.out.println("third view is loaded :(");

}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem using the code you show. Show us an [mcve] - something we can run unchanged which you have tested and definitely causes the problem.

Comment: @greg-449 do you mean that the second view is loaded without calling the third one? It is possible that there is something else affecting button behavior, but I have no idea what it might be. There is a TableViewer and a Label in the window that are modified in each view and some other buttons, that don't do anything at the moment.

Comment: You haven't shown us any code that loads views. I just tested what you showed us - those fragments of code work fine, the problem is somewhere else that you haven't shown us.

Comment: @greg-449 if after one click you have this message in the console: "third view is loaded :(" - there is a problem. If you don't, then the problem must be somewhere else. I am looking at my code right now trying to figure out what is the minimum that will cause the problem (I don't want to be yelled at for posting 500 lines of code).

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be because of the flow of operations going on here. 
button is clicked, so it is in a state of being selected. During this state, it calls load second view, where it sets up a new listener. 
I believe that the new listener gets called because the button is still in a state of being selected, or rather has not resolved yet.

Edit: I would be curious to see your code for the back button if what you say is true

Comment: That was my thought. I added a 1 second wait in the second view in between removing the listener and adding new one - the same result. Noticeably slower, but the first view jumped directly into third.

<code>
if (backListener != null) {
btnBack.removeSelectionListener(backListener);
}
backListener = new SelectionListener() {
Override
public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent event) {
initializeFirstView();
}
Override
public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent event) {
}
};

btnBack.addSelectionListener(backListener);</code>

Comment: what exactly would you like to see?

Answer (score 0):

This might be my local problem - I still haven't figured out why the two listeners are consecutively fired after one click, but I found (not very elegant solution) to get around the problem:

Because the two listeners are fired with the event that has the same event.time value, I created a field `eventTime` and in the nextButton's listener in the first view I set it with the value of event.time and then in the second view's listener I check

```
if (!(event.time == eventTime)) {
    loadThirdView();
}
```